# Which are the canonical sources for reading about Isa in Islam?

Tags: prophet-isa

Once I've read that Islam says Isa is going to return to Earth and fight a war. This is a different version of character personality that's given for Jesus in christianity were he says "Put your sword back in its place. for all who draw the sword will die by the sword". (I suppose Islam doesnt see the source where is quoted him saying that as a true source since it seems to be contradictory with someone later returning to fight a war) . I'm interested to read more about him in Islam to see how different they are portraited

Comment: There of different of opinions regarding the dajjal, mehdi and isa in the end of times, some deny it all, where as some deny some of it, and others believe in all of it. Islam has nothing against the statement Jesus/Isa said about the sword and war.

Comment: I'm not taking any source as the ultimate truth. That's why I would like to read more about Isa in Islam. But the sword statement to me sounds like "you shouldnt fight" which in my understanding is contradictory with someone going to a war. Perhaps the historical Isa/Jesus would indeed go to a war and wouldnt ask someone not to fight, I dont know

Comment: I think the teaching of the prophet Jesus, and the intention with his words "the one draws the sword, will die by the sword" rather was meant for people, who had no patience at all and as soon as any small problem would occur, they go with the sword and fight. If you read the history about islam, the meccan period was without any violence, even though the muslims was oppressed. Anyway, there are nothing in the Quran mentioning that Jesus will return to earth and fight a war. There are hadiths, but these hadiths about this topic have different of opinions about, muslims dont have to believe in